# how to add image as page in PDFBox Android

Tags: android, pdfbox

I have add [PdfBox Android port](https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android) in my android project.

I have wrote the following code

```
try
{
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    // page.set
    document.addPage(page);

    // Create a new font object selecting one of the PDF base fonts
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "myapp");
    File phone = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "image.jpg");
    FileInputStream mInput = new FileInputStream(phone);   
             PDStream steam1 = new PDStream(document, mInput);
    PDResources resource1 = new PDResources();
    PDImageXObject img = new PDImageXObject(steam1, resource1);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
    document, page);
    contentStream.drawImage(img, 100, 100);
    contentStream.close();
    document.save("Hello World.pdf");
    document.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

when I execute it goes well until following line

```
PDImageXObject img = new PDImageXObject(steam1, resource1);
```

I get following error

> java.io.IOException: null stream was not read

how to solve it? I think I am missing something. please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the JPEGFactory, not PDImageXObject:

```
PDImageXObject img = JPEGFactory.createFromStream(document, mInput);
```

delete the lines with PDResources and with PDStream. Thus your code would look like this:

```
try
{
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    // page.set
    document.addPage(page);

    // Create a new font object selecting one of the PDF base fonts
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "myapp");
    File phone = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "image.jpg");
    FileInputStream mInput = new FileInputStream(phone);   
    PDImageXObject img = JPEGFactory.createFromStream(document, mInput);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
    contentStream.drawImage(img, 100, 100);
    contentStream.close();
    document.save(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "Hello World.pdf");
    document.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

(This answer applies only to the Android version)

Comment: thanks for reply. but it is not able to find PDXObjectImage  and PDJpeg http://s18.postimg.org/i6gpxqeuh/a_Total.png

Comment: @OutSider Here's a new answer :-)

Comment: thanks for reply. it removed previous errors but now I am getting "/Hello World.pdf: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)". please help!

Comment: @OutSider this is beyond the scope of the PDFBox question, but I suspect that you must save to the same directory where you got your JPEG. I have changed my response accordingly.

Comment: works like a charm. May God bless you and your family and your future generation. you are a life saver man!